# curl issue while uploading files to ftp

Tags: bash, for-loop, curl, upload, ftp

I have an issue while I need from script to upload all files which stored in some directory. Every time I get this issue:

curl: (9) Server denied you to change to the given directory

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in /export/test/*
do
   curl -T ${file} ftp://192.168.10.10/${file} --user tester:psswd
done
```

I checked vsftpd config and I have permissions to write/read and when I do it manually It runs.

for example when I run this command, everything is OK.

```
 curl -T /export/test/testing.txt ftp://192.168.10.10/export/status/testing.txt --user tester:psswd
```

Have someone else also this problem? 
I don't have any idea how to solve it, I tried everything.

By the way: My ftp root folder is /var/www/stats  and I need to rewrite files in subfolders which is named: /var/www/stats/export/test.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED

my bad: error is in that file variable putting full path to server and I put one more slash there.
so final conclusion is this:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in /export/test/*
do
   curl -T ${file} ftp://192.168.10.10${file} --user tester:psswd
done
```

It works. Done.